# Access static IP page on remote server from local computer

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn

I have a page running on a static IP(192.168.x.x) at a fixed port number on a remote server running ubuntu.

I would like to access this page locally but haven't been able to do so. So far I have tried ssh tunneling using `ssh -L <PORT_local>:localhost:<PORT_remote> user@remote-machine-name` using this answer as reference: https://superuser.com/questions/891895/how-to-access-webpage-running-on-remote-server

But I haven't amanged to get this working. I see `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused` on my remote server once ssh login completes and I try to access the page localhost:<PORT_local> from my local computer. I made sure that <PORT_remote> is allowed over firewall using `ufw`. Also to note, my local computer and remote server are on VPN. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Hello. a good start is what is used on the local end? OS and software.

Comment: Local end is Windows at the moment, Windows 10